# PCB Layout Mentor Graphics - basic question about transmission lines and components

Tags: pcb-design, layout, siemens, mentor-pads

I am currently doing a PCB Layout for an amplifier and would like to know if there is any way to add a transmission line to the Layout. As far as I noticed there is no corresponding symbol for such a transmission line, so it has to be implemented in a different way. Does anyone know how I can add such a line to my layout? What option to use/where to enter?

Additionally - is it possible to add components such as RF Connector or any other Connector to the layout (although I care about RF Connector). I would like to place two such Connectors on two edges of the board but I don't know where to find these components. Would it be possible to add them to the layout? If so, how?

Below you will find screenshots of my project and layout (the layout one is more important I guess). Thank you in advance for any help and answers!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The transmission line can be done in the layout and routing stage, by specifying the line width, spacing above (or below) the reference plane, and other parameters that determine the Zo of the trace.

Comment: For the RF connectors, you (or your component librarian) need to create 1) the schematic symbol and 2) the footprint for the RF connector you want to use.  I'm surprised that one doesn't exist in the Mentor library.

Comment: @SteveSh Thank you so much for your comment! I would accept a reply, but unfortunately I can't because it's a comment. As for the RF Connectors in the Mentor library - you're right, unfortunately they don't exist, but I did more research and you can download such a component from the PartQuest website and then upload it to PADS (I thought there was some option to add them differently but unfortunately it looks like not). Thanks again!